# Add image to Joomla JToolBar custom link button

Tags: joomla, components, jtoolbar

Hi I have created a custom button link in the admin section of my component, something like this:

```
$bar = & JToolBar::getInstance('toolbar');
$bar->appendButton( 'Link', 'export', 'Export', 'index.php?option=com_component&task=export&format=raw' );
```

However no image is assigned to it and I don't know how to assign one to the button. Does anyone know how I can do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to create CSS class called `icon-32-export` with image background.

Here is an example:

```
<?php

// Add CSS class to the document, it's better to have it in external CSS document
$imgPath = JRoute::_('/administrator/templates/khepri/images/toolbar/icon-32-new.png');
JFactory::getDocument()->addStyleDeclaration(".icon-32-export { background: url($imgPath); }");

//
$bar = & JToolBar::getInstance('toolbar');
$url = JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_component&task=export&format=raw');
$bar->appendButton( 'Link', 'export', 'Export', $url);

?>
```